# Как ускорить работу JQuery (JavaScript)?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Дело в том, что задал с помощью `jQuery` размеры веб страницы в соответствии с размером экрана.

Например, беру ширину экрана, присваиваю к переменной `width`. Потом размер `wrapper`'а задаю как (`width` / 2).

Проблема: При загрузке страницы, грузится страница медленно, а именно как бы она открывается на всю страницу, а потом резко сокращается и становится на свое место. При этом процесс виден и доставляет неудобства.

Может что то не так делаю, или как то можно ускорить работу скрипта?

Comment: может страница грузится медленно, потому что интернет медленный или она исполняет ещё несколько мегабайт кода?

Почему бы просто не сделать нормально верстку?

Comment: ОФФТОП: а нельзя в CSS задать 50% для ширины wrapper'a и 100% для body?

Comment: @Genson процентами дела не идут. При каждом изменении размеров окна она искажается

Answer (score 3):

Давайте будем честными - 99% случаев медленной работы той или иной библиотеки на самом деле сводятся не к проблемам библиотеки, а к тому, что всегда наличествует явная корреляция между скоростью выполнения кода и квалификацией разработчика. Говоря русским языком, вы уверены, что в медленной работе виновата именно JQuery, а не вы, или какой-то ваш код, выполняемый вместе с тем, о котором вы говорите? Ведь наверняка эта библиотека не пользовалась бы такой популярностью среди десятков тысяч (а может, и миллионов, кто знает) разработчиков, будь у нее такие проблемы с производительностью? 
А вообще, конечно, было бы куда лучше, если бы вы продемонстрировали пример своих скриптов на jsfiddle - гадание на  кофейной гуще явно не удел программистов

З.Ы. Тем не менее, по сравнению с рядом других библиотек (и естественно, с чистым JS) JQuery [проигрывает в производительности](http://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/188254/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // выполняйте свой код здесь, когда вся страница уже загрузилась.
})
```